# Shift rows inside each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the current dataframe:

```
+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| CustomerID | TimeKey      | Quantity | Cumulative |
+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| 1          | '2018-01-07' | 0        | 0          |
| 1          | '2018-01-13' | 1        | 1          |
| 1          | '2018-01-13' | 1        | 2          |
| 2          | '2018-01-17' | 1        | 1          |
| 3          | '2018-01-18' | 0        | 0          |
| 1          | '2018-01-20' | 0        | 2          |
| 2          | '2018-01-21' | 0        | 1          |
| 3          | '2018-01-23' | 1        | 1          |
+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
```

In which the "Cumulative" columns was calculated this way:

```
df['Cumulative'] = df.groupby('CustomerID')['Quantity'].cumsum()
```

BUT, what i really wanted would be this:

```
+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| CustomerID | TimeKey      | Quantity | Cumulative |
+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
| 1          | '2018-01-07' | 0        | 0          |
| 1          | '2018-01-13' | 1        | 0          |
| 1          | '2018-01-13' | 1        | 1          |
| 2          | '2018-01-17' | 1        | 0          |
| 3          | '2018-01-18' | 0        | 0          |
| 1          | '2018-01-20' | 0        | 2          |
| 2          | '2018-01-21' | 0        | 1          |
| 3          | '2018-01-23' | 1        | 0          |
+------------+--------------+----------+------------+
```

(Dataframes are always sorted by time_key to make things easier)

And what i mean is: I want the cumulative to be the sum of all past rows, NOT including the same row.
Basically, i want to shift the values of every customer's cumulative by one row.

Comment: You can adopt YO and BEN_W's solution. `GroupBy.apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum().fillna(0))`